# I used mysqli_fetch_assoc() to fetch the array in decreasing order and it fetches in a different manner.How can I correct it?

Tags: php

I used mysqli_fetch_assoc function to fetch the rows in a decreasing order but when I echo the associative array of table "posts"(there are only three rows in the posts table- post 1,post 2 , post 3)

it prints in this manner:([I have added a screenshot of this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKL4n.jpg) )

post 3 (edit/delete)

post 3 (edit/delete)
post 2 (edit/delete)

post 3 (edit/delete)
post 2 (edit/delete)
post 1 (edit/delete)

I wanted it to print in this manner:

post 3 (edit/delete)
post 2 (edit/delete)
post 1 (edit/delete)

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myblog");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $posts = "";

    if ($count > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $date = $row['date'];


        $admin = "
               <div>
               <a href='del_post.php?pid=$id'>DELETE </a>
               <a href='edit_post.php?pid=$id'>EDIT</a>
               </div>
               ";
        $posts .= "<div><h4>$title</h4><h3>$date</h3><p>$content</p>$admin</div>";

        echo $posts;
      }
    } else {
      echo "there is nothing to show";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Just move `echo $posts;` outside of the loop and problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon what [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) commented - each time through the loop you are concatenating some data to the `$posts` variable and then printing it, but you are never resetting `$posts` to an empty string.

Some sample code:

```
$rows = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
$posts = '';

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $posts .= $row;
  echo $posts;
}
```

The first time through this loop you will print `a`, the second time you will print `ab` and the third time you will print `abc`.

There are (at least) two ways to resolve this, you can either clear `$posts` at the beginning of the `while` loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $posts = '';
```

Or you can move the printing of `$posts` to after the `while` loop completes:

```
  $posts .= "<div><h4>$title</h4><h3>$date</h3><p>$content</p>$admin</div>";
}
echo $posts;
```

A third option is to just not use the `$posts` variable at all:

```
echo "<div><h4>$title</h4><h3>$date</h3><p>$content</p>$admin</div>";
```